# Why are these two Sylow subgroups disjoint?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

I have the following problem:

> Let $G$ be a finite group with $card(G)=p^2q$ with $p<q$ two prime numbers. We denote $s_q$ the number of $q$-Sylow subgroups of $G$ and similarly for $p$. I have just shown that $s_q\in \{1,p^2\}$. Now I want to show that $$\bigcup_{S\in Syl_q(G)}S\setminus \{1\}=\dot\bigcup_{S\in Syl_q(G)}S\setminus \{1\}$$i.e. that for $S,T\in Syl_q(G)$ with $S\neq T$ we have that $S\setminus \{1\}\cap T\setminus \{1\}=\emptyset$.

But somehow I don't see why this needs to be true in our case. Could someone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S\cap T$ is a subgroup of $S$ and $T$, then its order divides $|S|=|T|=q$. Since $q$ is a prime, then either $|S\cap T|=1$ or $|S\cap T|=q$. Since $S\neq T$  it must hold $|S\cap T|=1$, which means $S\cap T=\{1_G\}$, therefore $(S\setminus\{1_G\}) \cap (T\setminus\{1_G\}) =\emptyset$

Comment: why do we know that $S\cap T$ is a subgroup of $S,T$

Comment: The intersection of two subgroups is always a subgroup. You can check easily the axioms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup)

Comment: But shouldn't it be a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Yes, but  $S\cap T$ is also contained in $S$ and $T$, so it is a subgroup of each of them

Comment: ah perfect thanks!